# choosing nodes color according to their name

Tags: r, colors, grouping, igraph

I have many igraph objects representing connections among member of different groups. A simple example of my graph data sets is like as follows:

```
library(igraph)
m<-matrix(data = c("a1_ghj",    "a1_phj",
                   "b2_ghj",    "c1_pht",
                   "c1_ght",    "a1_ghi",
                   "g5_pht",    "d2_phj",
                   "r5_phj",    "u6_pht"), ncol = 2)
))

g<-graph_from_edgelist(m)
g
```

In the first case, I want to plot this graph regarding that each vertex name that have similar characters after the `_` it means that they are in a same group and they should have a same random color. However, as the number of groups in different graphs are various, I don't know how coloring them can be possible in this case. Anyone can help on this issue?

Comment: You say "that have similar characters after the _"  All of your examples seem kind of the same to me - they all have h in the center.  Do they only need to be the same if they are equal or is there some other similarity metric that influences the color choice? Are ghi and ghi more alike than ght?

Comment: @G5W I had to say same characters. ghi is a different name group of ght.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sub` on the vertex names to get the suffixes. Then treat those as a factor to get different colors for each type of node.

```
Suffixes = factor(sub(".*_", "", names(V(g))))
Suffixes
 [1] ghj ghi phj pht ghj phj pht phj ght pht
Levels: ghi ghj ght phj pht
plot(g, vertex.color=rainbow(5)[Suffixes])
```

[image: Colored nodes]