# Coloring nodes of a graph according to the different scales

Tags: r, colors, substring, nodes, igraph

I want to plot different data sets as igraph objects. They can be like as follows:

```
library(igraph)
m<-matrix(data = c("a1_ghj",    "a1_phj",
                   "b2_ghj",    "c1_pht",
                   "c1_ght",    "a1_ghi",
                   "g5_pht",    "d2_phj",
                   "r5_phj",    "u6_pht"), ncol = 2)
))

g<-graph_from_edgelist(m)
g
```

The color of their nodes should be specified by different scales for example they are as follows:

```
aa  qwr asd rty fgh vbn iop ert
ghj 1.8 -0.5    0.2 0.62    0.74    0.3 1.6
ght 2.5 -1  4.1 0.29    0.91    0.9 2
pht -3.5    3   -3.1    -0.9    0.62    -0.6    -9.2
phj -3.5    3   -1.8    -0.74   0.62    -0.7    -8.2
ghi 2.8 -2.5    4.4 1.19    0.88    0.5 3.7
```

In the name of nodes, after `_` , the name of group that the node is a member of that is displayed. In the scale table, columns display type of the scale and rows illustrate the name of the groups. 
For plotting these graphs I need a function to normalize these scales between -1 and 1, then specifies color to the nodes regarding the values of a chosen scale type in the table. Anybody help me on this issue?

Comment: Is it correct that you want to make 7 different graphs - one for each of qwr asd rty fgh vbn iop ert ?

Comment: More specifically, I like to be able to plot a graph according to what scale type I choose. @G5W

Answer (score 0):

First of all,  as in [The earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49988650/4752675)
you can use `sub` on the vertex names to get the suffixes.

```
Suffixes = factor(sub(".*_", "", names(V(g))))
```

So the question becomes how to use the different scales to choose the colors
for the nodes. You asked to scale from -1 to 1, but actually I have scaled 
0 to 1, because that is the type of argument expected by the function produced 
by `colorRamp`.

Your scaling data

```
RawScales = read.table(text="aa  qwr asd rty fgh vbn iop ert
ghj 1.8  -0.5    0.2   0.62    0.74    0.3     1.6
ght 2.5    -1    4.1   0.29    0.91    0.9       2
pht -3.5    3   -3.1   -0.9    0.62    -0.6   -9.2
phj -3.5    3   -1.8   -0.74   0.62    -0.7   -8.2
ghi 2.8  -2.5    4.4    1.19    0.88    0.5    3.7",
header=TRUE)
```

I will use both of the `qwr` and `rty` scales as examples.

Scale between 0 and 1.

```
qwr_Scaled = (RawScales$qwr - min(RawScales$qwr)) / 
    (max(RawScales$qwr) - min(RawScales$qwr)) 

rty_Scaled = (RawScales$rty - min(RawScales$rty)) / 
    (max(RawScales$rty) - min(RawScales$rty))
```

Set up a function to create color scales. Note:  orange is the minimum value, red is the maximum value.

```
Color = colorRamp(c("orange", "yellow", "white",  "pink", "red"))
```

Use the function to create a vector of colors for the nodes.

```
ColVals_qwr = rgb(Color(qwr_Scaled), maxColorValue=255)
names(ColVals_qwr) = RawScales$aa

ColVals_rty = rgb(Color(rty_Scaled), maxColorValue=255)
names(ColVals_rty) = RawScales$aa
```

Now plot using the color scales. I have added an explicit layout of the nodes so that the two plots would be comparable.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2), mar=c(5, 1,3,1))
LO = layout_with_fr(g)
plot(g, vertex.color=ColVals_qwr[Suffixes], frame=TRUE)
plot(g, vertex.color=ColVals_rty[Suffixes], frame=TRUE)
```

[image: Two scalings]